# Splitting names and rootnames using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple program that prompts the user to type in a filename with its extension and my program will separate the filename and the rootname. Essentially, my goal looks like this below:

```
userinput=Jack.html
filename=Jack
rootname=html
```

I was able to separate it using the split function and accessing the separately but my problem is when the user input has multiple periods for example like this

```
userinput= Jack.1.2.html
filename=Jack.1.2
rootname=html
```

How do I go about separating the user input when it has multiple periods. 
Here is my code. I want to work for multiple periods as well:

```
var userinput, splitinput; 
var rootname, filename;

userinput= prompt('Enter filename:') //
splitinput=userinput.split('.')
filename= splitinput[0]
rootname=splitinput[1]+ userinput[2]
console.log(filename)
console.log(rootname)
```

Comment: `rootname = splitinput.pop()`, and everything else joined is a file name? Though "rootname" is rather an extension name than a rootname ...

Comment: `'Jack.1.2.html'.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')` will give `Jack.1.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `pop()` and `join()`. Effectively we split the string by periods, then pop off the last one, and then we get the two sections of the string (rootname and filename).

Here is a **live demo**:

```js
var userinput = prompt('Enter filename:');
var splitinput = userinput.split('.');
var rootname = splitinput.pop();
var filename = splitinput.join(".");

document.getElementById("output1").textContent = filename;
document.getElementById("output2").textContent = rootname;
```

```html
<div>Filename: <span id="output1"></span></div>
<div>Rootname: <span id="output2"></span></div>
```

Comment: OP did declare each variable, note the first two lines.

Comment: @bonesbrigade Whoops, you're right. Just very unused to seeing it that way. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Split it by the position of the last period, like this:

```js
    var userinput; 
    var rootname, filename;
    
    userinput= prompt('Enter filename:') //
    filename= userinput.substring(0,userinput.lastIndexOf('.'))
    rootname=userinput.substring(userinput.lastIndexOf('.')+1)
    console.log(filename)
    console.log(rootname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.slice()` with a negative argument to trim the last part of the array off (e.g., `html`), then re-join:

```
var userinput = prompt('Enter filename:'),
    filename = userinput.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.') || userinput;

alert('Filename: ' + filename);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u3nb2ctL/

Comment: Yeah, mistyped it (see my comment above). One minute.